# Как передать ssh ключ через secrets в GitHub Actions?

Tags: docker, ssh, github-actions

Как можно сохранить или передать напрямую приватную часть SSH ключа?

Не рабочий вариант:

```
      - name: "[build] run docker build"
        run: >
          echo $TMP_SSH_KEY > tmp_secret;
          docker build
          --tag $DOCKER_IMG_NAME:$DOCKER_IMG_TAG
          --tag $DOCKER_IMG_NAME:latest
          --file .docker/app.dockerfile
          --ssh github-ssh-key=tmp_secret
          .
        shell: "bash"
        env:
          TMP_SSH_KEY: ${{ secrets.GHA_TOKEN }}
```

Вываливается с ошибкой:

```
could not parse ssh: [github-ssh-key=tmp_secret]: failed to parse tmp_secret: ssh: no key found
```

Во время сборки образа на локальной машине я указываю путь к ключу и он собирается без ошибок. Этот процесс подтягивает несколько закрытых репозиториев для установки Python requirements.txt.

При использование `gha` (GitHub Actions) отваливается с ошибкой. Не смог найти в докумунтации как передавать секреты в `docker` из `gha`.

**Ссылки**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481933
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets
- https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/

Answer (score 1):

Решил эту задачи через сохранине секрета в файл и дальнейшего монтирования в докер `--volume`